# Guessing a missing value based on historical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, math

Let's assume i have 100 different kinds of items, each item got a name and a physical weight.
I know the names of all 100 items but only the weight of 80 items.

When i ship items, i pack them in groups of 10 and sum the weight of these items.
Due to some items are missing their weight, this will give an inaccurate sum when im about to ship.

I have different shipments with missing weights

Shipment 1

| Item Name | Item Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Item 2 | 10 |
| Item 27 | 20 |
| Item 42 | 20 |
| Item 71 | - |
| Item 77 | - |

Total weight: 75

Shipment 2

| Item Name | Item Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Item 2 | 10 |
| Item 27 | 20 |
| Item 42 | 20 |
| Item 71 | - |
| Item 92 | - |

Total weight: 90

Shipment 3

| Item Name | Item Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Item 2 | 10 |
| Item 27 | 20 |
| Item 42 | 20 |
| Item 55 | 35 |
| Item 77 | - |

Total weight: 100

Since some of the shipments share the same items with missing weights and i have the shipments total weight, is there a way with machine learning to determine the weight of these items without im unpacking the entire shipment?
Or would it just be a, in this case, 100x3 Matrix with a lot of empty values?

At this point im not really sure if i should use some type of regression to solve this or if its just a matrix, that would expand a lot if i had n more items to ship.
I also wondered if this was some type of knapsack problem, but i hope anyone can guide my in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Forget about machine learning. This is a simple system of linear equations. `w_71 + w_77 = 25; w_71 + w_92 = 40; w_77 = 15`.

Comment: You could try solving it with [sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve), or [scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq), or [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about machine learning. This is a simple system of linear equations.

```
w_71 + w_77 = 25
w_71 + w_92 = 40
w_77 = 15
```

You can solve it with [sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve), or [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html), or [scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq), or [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

- `sympy.linsolve` is maybe the easiest to understand if you are not familiar with matrices; however, if the system is underdetermined, then instead of returning a particular solution to the system, `sympy.linsolve` will return the general solution in parametric form.
- `scipy.lstsq` or `numpy.lstsq` expect the problem to be given in matrix form. If there is more than one possible solution, they will return the most "average" solution. However, they cannot take any positivity constraint into account: they might return a solution where one of the variables is negative. You can maybe fix this behaviour by adding a new equation to the system to manually force a variable to be positive, then solve again.
- `scipy.linprog` expects the problem to be given in matrix form; it also expects you to specify a linear objective function, to choose which particular solution is "best" in case there is more than one possible solution. `linprog` also considers that all variables are nonnegative by default, or allows you to specify explicit bounds for the variables yourself. It also allows you to add inequality constraints, in addition to the equations, if you wish to.

### Using [sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve)

```py
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
from sympy import symbols

w71, w77, w92 = symbols('w71 w77 w92')

eqs = [w71+w77-25, w71+w92-40, w77-15]

solution = linsolve(eqs, [w71, w77, w92])
# solution = {(10, 15, 30)}
```

In your example, there is only one possible solution, so `linsolve` returned that solution: `w71 = 10, w77 = 15, w92 = 30`.

However, in case there is more than one possible solution, `linsolve` will return a parametric form for the general solution:

```py
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')

eqs = [x+y-10, y+z-20]

solution = linsolve(eqs, [x, y, z])
# solution = {(z - 10, 20 - z, z)}
```

Here there is an infinity of possible solutions. `linsolve` is telling us that we can pick any value for `z`, and then we'll get the corresponding `x` and `y` as `x = z - 10` and `y = 20 - z`.

### Using [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

`lstsq` expects the system of equations to be given in matrix form. If there is more than one possible solution, then it will return the most "average" solution. For instance, if the system of equation is simply `x + y = 10`, then `lstsq` will return the particular solution `x = 5, y = 5` and will ignore more "extreme" solutions such as `x = 10, y = 0`.

```py
from numpy.linalg import lstsq

# w_71 + w_77 = 25
# w_71 + w_92 = 40
# w_77 = 15
A = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
b = [25, 40, 15]

solution = lstsq(A, b)
solution[0]
# array([10., 15., 30.])
```

Here `lstsq` found the unique solution, `w71 = 10, w77=15, w92 = 30`.

```py
# x + y = 10
# y + z = 20
A = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
b = [10, 20]

solution = lstsq(A, B)
solution[0]
# array([-3.55271368e-15,  1.00000000e+01,  1.00000000e+01])
```

Here `lstsq` had to choose a particular solution, and chose the one it considered most "average", `x = 0, y = 10, z = 10`. You might want to round the solution to integers.

One drawback of `lstsq` is that it doesn't take into account your non-negativity constraint. That is, it might return a solution where one of the variables is negative:

```py
# x + y = 2
# y + z = 20
A = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1])
b = [2, 20]

solution = lstsq(A, b)
solution[0]
# array([-5.33333333,  7.33333333, 12.66666667])
```

See how `lstsq` ignored the possible positive solution `x = 1, y = 1, z = 18` and instead returned the solution it considered most "average", `x = -5.33, y = 7.33, z = 12.67`.

One way to fix this is to add an equation yourself to force the offending variable to be positive. For instance, here we noticed that `lstsq` wanted `x` to be negative, so we can manually force `x` to be equal to `1` instead, and solve again:

```py
# x + y = 2
# y + z = 20
# x = 1
A = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
b = [2, 20, 1]

solution = lstsq(A, b)
solution[0]
# array([ 1.,  1., 19.])
```

Now that we manually forced `x` to be 1, `lstsq` found solution `x=1, y=1, z=19` which we're more happy with.

### Using [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html)

The particularity of `linprog` is that it expects you to specify the "objective" used to choose a particular solution, in case there is more than one possible solution.

Also, `linprog` allows you to specify bounds for the variables. The default is that all variables are nonnegative, which is what you want.

```py
from scipy.optimize import linprog

# w_71 + w_77 = 25
# w_71 + w_92 = 40
# w_77 = 15
A = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
b = [25, 40, 15]
c = [1, 1, 1] # coefficients for objective: minimise w71 + w77 + w92.

solution = linprog(c, A_eq = A, b_eq = b)
solution.x
# array([10., 15., 30.])
```

Comment: Such a good answer with many possibilities. Thank you very much! I will definitely look into these solutions :)

Comment: One thing. Lets say i have 25000 items instead of only 100 and perhaps 1000 shipments. Wouldn't linear equations only give me infinity solutions so in practice; with a low amount of shipments i will never get concrete values of the physical weights?

Comment: @Vestezen `sympy.linsolve` would only give you general solutions, yes, but in a form that could make it easier for you to generate particular solutions. The others, `numpy.lstsq` and `scipy.linprog`, will all give you particular solutions, never general solutions.